# While loop within a for loop, is there an easier and faster way?

Tags: r

I have the following data set, which consists of around 64000 rows:

```
    Trial.time Recording.time X.center Y.center  Area    Areachange Elongation   Distance.moved Movement.Moving...Center.point.
2      300.030          0.000 -49.1651  31.9676 0.917085    0.65113   0.851349              -                               -
22     300.696          0.666 -48.4404  31.9945 0.816206   0.715326   0.831207       0.725139                               1
24     300.763          0.733  -47.996  32.0696 0.834547   0.412688   0.856234       0.450784                               1
33     301.063          1.033 -47.6583  32.0598  0.75201   0.137563   0.716028       0.337775                               1
41     301.330          1.299 -47.3385  32.0139 0.843718   0.302638   0.838526       0.323117                               1
98     303.230          3.199 -47.3914  31.6981 0.944598    1.26558   0.847969        0.32022                               1
113    303.730          3.699 -47.3807  31.0614  0.86206    1.24724   0.761099       0.636771                               1
114    303.763          3.733 -47.1308  30.3858  1.00879     1.1005   0.809162        0.72036                               1
116    303.830          3.799 -47.1914  30.0551  1.01796   0.440201   0.831924       0.336155                               1
```

In general it describes the movement (Distance.Moved) of an object at a specific Recording.time. If the Recording.time of two consecutive rows is smaller than 0.035, both rows belong to one single movement. In contrast, if it is bigger the time points represent two separate movements. My job is to determine the length of each movement, so how many consecutive rows give one movement and the total Distance.moved within the movement. I wrote the following code, which works but is very slow and I want to ask if you have any idea how to improve the speed.

```
    time <- c()
j.final <- c()

#Go through all rows of the data.frame
for(i in 1:length(data2[,1])){
  i <- 1
  j <- 1
  if (!is.na(data2$Recording.time[i+1])){

    # As long as the distance between two consecutive time points is smaller than 0.035, increase the counter by one
    while (data2$Recording.time[i+1]-data2$Recording.time[i] <= 0.035){
      j <- j+1
      i <- i+1
    }
    # Save the number of consecutive time points
    j.final <- rbind(j.final,j)
    # Save the time of the last movement frame 
    time <- rbind(time,data2$Recording.time[j])
    # Delete the amount of rows that gave one single movement 
    data2 <- data2[-(1:j),]
  }
}   
final <- cbind(j.final,time)

#Same as above... Continouslz rows out of the data.frame
data2 <- data1
for (i in 1:length(j.final)){
  Dtotal <- sum(data2$Distance.moved[1:j.final[i]])
  distance <- rbind(distance, Dtotal)
  data2 <- data2[-(1:j.final[i]),]
}
final <- cbind(final,distance)
dimnames(final) <- list(NULL,c("Frames","Time","Distance"))
epicfinal <- as.data.frame(final)
```

The final result looks like this (Please dont mind the velocity)

```
  Frames  Time  Distance    velocity
1      1 0.033 0.0407652 0.001386017
2     18 0.666 1.4887506 0.911115367
3      3 0.799 0.0912680 0.009309336
4      7 1.066 0.3703880 0.088152344
5      2 1.166 0.0371303 0.002524860
6      3 1.299 0.1013617 0.010338893
```

Comment: Look into `lead`, `lag`, `cumsum` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As zx8754 pointed out, this is easily achieved with `lag` (or, better, his fast implementation inside `data.table`: `shift`) and `cumsum` functions.
I use the `data.table` package for speed (note that the syntax is much different from classical `data.frames` as with `data.table` you can put expression in the `j` argument when subsetting the table, as opposed to simply selecting columns in `data.frame`).

```r
library(data.table)

## VARIABLE CREATION:
# Create a column which indicates the lag between two observations
data$lag <- data$Recording.time-shift(data$Recording.time) 
data$lag[1] <- 0 # The first value is always NA: fix it
data$newmovement <- data$lag<0.035 # Binary variable: T if there's a new movement, F otherwise
data$movement_index <- cumsum(data$newmovement) # Index to identify the movement

## COMPUTATIONS:
# Use the data.table package for fast computations
data <- data.table(data)
data[,.(length_movement=.N, # Length (nrows) for each movement
        total_distance=sum(Distance.moved,na.rm = T)), # Total distance: sum of distances for each movement
         by=movement_index] # Subset by=movement_index

#    movement_index length_movement total_distance
# 1:              1               7       2.793806
# 2:              2               2       1.056515
```

Note that the `##VARIABLE CREATION` part could be achieved through the `data.table` package, too.
This will probably result in an additional speed boost, you could do that by replacing the first part of the code with the following:

```
## VARIABLE CREATION:
data[,lag:=Recording.time-shift(Recording.time)][1,lag:=0L]
data[,newmovement:=lag<0.035]
data[,movement_index:=cumsum(newmovement)]
```

Comment: `data$lag<0.035` is already a binary variable. There is no need for `ifelse` just use `!(data$lag<0.035)` or `data$lag>=0.035`. You can do the same (without `replace`) within data.table. `cumsum` will coerce logical values automatically to integers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. To solve my problem however you have to use shift instead of lag (data$lag <- data$Recording.time-shift(data$Recording.time)).

Comment: @Urumpel You're perfectly right: `shift` is, indeed, a faster implementation of `lead` or `lag`. So, even thought it's not mandatory to use it, I only see advantages in using it in this case as I'm already using `data.table`.  
I edited my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @hellter I have another question. Is there an easy way to include the end time point (Recording.time) of the movement in the final table?

Comment: Yes, once you have created the `movement_index` you could simply subset `data` `by=movement_index` and keep the last row ('`.N`') in correpsondence of the column you want. To do this, you need to use `.SD` in the `j` argument. For Recording.time, it should look like this: `data[,.SD[.N,.(last_recording_time=Recording.time)],movement_index]`